# extjs 3.4 How to use prompts UI?

Tags: javascript, user-interface, extjs3

I have a requirement of not using radio buttons to track a 'Yes' or 'No' option in a dialog box. Instead use something like a prompt which will have Yes, No and Cancel as prompts. (No explicit Submit button unlike in the above case). Is there anyway to do this using extjs 3.3/3.4?

I have been reading the documentation but do not see any support for prompts. Any help or ideas on this will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

there is Ext.Msg library to use. 
http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.MessageBox